# ng animate not working first time loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I need to animate the elements one by one. It is working one by one using `ng-enter-stagger` and `ng-leave-stagger` but at the time of loading the animation is not coming.

This is the code:

html

```
<div ng-repeat='animate in animations' ng-class='animation'>Test</div>
```

css

```
.animation.ng-enter-stagger, .animation.ng-leave-stagger, .animation.ng-move-stagger {
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
animation-delay: 0.3s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0;
animation-duration: 0;
}
.animation.ng-enter {
-webkit-animation:2s ease-in-out all;
animation:2s ease-in-out all;

animation-name:flipInX;
-webkit-animation-name:flipInX;
}
.flipInAni.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {

animation-name:flipInX;
-webkit-animation-name:flipInX;
}
.animation.ng-leave {
-webkit-animation:1s ease-in-out all;
animation:1s ease-in-out all;
animation-name:flipOutX;
-webkit-animation-name:flipInX;
}
.animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
animation-name:flipOutX;
-webkit-animation-name:flipOutX;
}
```

Comment: what version are you loading? could be a version problem.see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910611/angular-nganimate-not-working-first-time-on-page-load

Comment: I am using version 1.2, changed to 1.2.28 & even 1.3 but still the problem exsist